# Jquery Append :checked Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

what I need to do is when I click in test1 checkbox show the div in `show-content` the div id item 1 :

```
<div class="show-content">
    <div id="item1">
      test1
    </div>
```

when I click in test2 checkbox show the div in `show-content` the div id item 2 :

```
<div class="show-content">
    <div id="item2">
      test2
    </div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P3zMu/271/

```js
var increment2 = 1;
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  var $li = $(this).parent('li').get(0);
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $('#selected_items').append('<span class="label label-primary" selected-item="' + $li.id + '_selected">' + $($li).find('label').text() + '</span>');
  } else {
    $('#selected_items > span[selected-item^="' + $li.id + '"]').remove();
  }
$("span").bind("click", function() {
  $(this).remove();
  var selectedText = $(this).attr('selected-item');
  selectedText = selectedText.split('_');
    $('li#' + selectedText[0]).find('input').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li style="text-indent: 0px;">
    <a id="selected_items">Refined by:</a>
  </li>
  <div class="collapse-link">
    <a aria-controls="collapseCommittee" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-target="#collapseCommittee" data-toggle="collapse">click bellow to include</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="bill-type">
    <li id="item1">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test1</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">222</span>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test2</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">33</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

<h1> show the content </h1>

  <div class="show-content">
    <div id="item1">
      test1
    </div>
    <div id="item2">
      test2
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have multiple elements with the same id, and Id show never exists more than once. use `class` if needed.

```
$(".show-content [class^=item]").hide();
$('#selected_items span').each(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("selected-item").replace("_selected","");
  $(".show-content ."+ id).show()
})
```

I've added the code above. Hope this is what your looking for.

**Demo**

```js
var increment2 = 1;
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  var $li = $(this).parent('li').get(0);
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#selected_items').append('<span class="label label-primary" selected-item="' + $li.id + '_selected">' + $($li).find('label').text() + '</span>');
  } else {
    $('#selected_items > span[selected-item^="' + $li.id + '"]').remove();
  }
  
  $(".show-content [class^=item]").hide();
  $('#selected_items span').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("selected-item").replace("_selected","");
    $(".show-content ."+ id).show()
  })
  
  $("span").bind("click", function() {
    $(this).remove();
    var selectedText = $(this).attr('selected-item');
    selectedText = selectedText.split('_');
    $('li#' + selectedText[0]).find('input').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li style="text-indent: 0px;">
    <a id="selected_items">Refined by:</a>
  </li>
  <div class="collapse-link">
    <a aria-controls="collapseCommittee" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-target="#collapseCommittee" data-toggle="collapse">click bellow to include</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="bill-type">
    <li id="item1">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test1</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">222</span>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test2</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">33</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <h1> show the content </h1>

  <div class="show-content">
    <div class="item1">
      test1
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      test2
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your duplicating ID's, not ideal.  But will still work in this case.

Below I'm initially setting the display:none on your sections.

And then just use toggle class on them, and finding the same id inside the show-content div.

```js
var increment2 = 1;
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  var $li = $(this).parent('li').get(0);
  
  var id = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');  
  $('.show-content #' + id).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
  
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $('#selected_items').append('<span class="label label-primary" selected-item="' + $li.id + '_selected">' + $($li).find('label').text() + '</span>');
  } else {
    $('#selected_items > span[selected-item^="' + $li.id + '"]').remove();
  }
$("span").bind("click", function() {
  $(this).remove();
  var selectedText = $(this).attr('selected-item');
  selectedText = selectedText.split('_');
    $('li#' + selectedText[0]).find('input').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li style="text-indent: 0px;">
    <a id="selected_items">Refined by:</a>
  </li>
  <div class="collapse-link">
    <a aria-controls="collapseCommittee" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-target="#collapseCommittee" data-toggle="collapse">click bellow to include</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="bill-type">
    <li id="item1">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test1</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">222</span>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test2</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">33</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

<h1> show the content </h1>

  <div class="show-content">
    <div id="item1" style="display:none">
      test1
    </div>
    <div id="item2" style="display:none">
      test2
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If duplication of Id's is not ideal why do you not change it then?

Comment: thanks keith, works as a charm, but if I remove the label: <span class="label label-primary" selected-item="item1_selected">test1</span> should hide the div too understan? right now it is not doing this.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen  Because it still works, and that's how the OP has his markup, I'm not here to enforce my POV.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. multiple same ids, not good one .so change with class name
2. HIDE all the `show-content` children before showing particular item

```js
var increment2 = 1;
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  var $li = $(this).closest('li');
  $('.show-content').find('div').hide();
   
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $('.show-content').find('div[class="'+$li.attr('id')+'"]').show()
    $('#selected_items').append('<span class="label label-primary" selected-item="' + $li.id + '_selected">' + $($li).find('label').text() + '</span>');
  } else {
    $('#selected_items > span[selected-item^="' + $li.id + '"]').remove();
  }
  $("span").bind("click", function() {
    $(this).remove();
    var selectedText = $(this).attr('selected-item');
    selectedText = selectedText.split('_');
    $('li#' + selectedText[0]).find('input').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```css
.test1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.show-content div{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li style="text-indent: 0px;">
    <a id="selected_items">Refined by:</a>
  </li>
  <div class="collapse-link">
    <a aria-controls="collapseCommittee" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-target="#collapseCommittee" data-toggle="collapse">click bellow to include</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="bill-type">
    <li id="item1">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test1</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">222</span>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label for="">test2</label>
      <span for="" class="pull-right">33</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="show-content">
    <div class="item1">
      test1
    </div>

    <div class="item2">
      test2
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and CSS:

```js
$('[data-checked-toggle]').each(function(i) {
    var thisCheckbox = $(this);
    var thisTarget = $( thisCheckbox.data('checkedToggle') );
    thisCheckbox.on('change', function(e) {
     thisTarget.toggleClass('is-visible', thisCheckbox.is(':checked'));
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.show-content > div {
    display: none;
}
.show-content > div.is-visible {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <label for="checkbox1">
        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" data-checked-toggle="#item1" /> test1
    </label>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="checkbox2">
        <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" data-checked-toggle="#item2" /> test2
    </label>
</p>

<div class="show-content">
    <div id="item1">
        test1
    </div>
    <div id="item2">
        test2
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P3zMu/273/).

This way you have great control:

- inside HTML you define which element is controlled by checkbox, anywhere on page
- inside CSS you decide how to present the element, it does not have to be invisible - is easy when you add/remove class

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple same `id`'s you can use custom `data` attribute and then `toggle` those elements based on checkbox.

```js
$('.show-content > div').hide();

$(".bill-type input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).parent('li').attr('id');
  $('.show-content > div[data-target="' + id + '"]').toggle($(this).is(':checked'))
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bill-type">
  <li id="item1">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label for="">test1</label>
    <span for="" class="pull-right">222</span>
  </li>
  <li id="item2">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label for="">test2</label>
    <span for="" class="pull-right">33</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="show-content">
  <div data-target="item1">test1</div>
  <div data-target="item2">test2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code. i just added two id on checkbox.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
<li style="text-indent: 0px;">
    <a id="selected_items">Refined by:</a>
</li>
<div class="collapse-link">
    <a aria-controls="collapseCommittee" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-target="#collapseCommittee" data-toggle="collapse">click bellow to include</a>
</div>
<ul class="bill-type">
    <li id="item1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
        <label for="">test1</label>
        <span for="" class="pull-right">222</span>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
        <label for="">test2</label>
        <span for="" class="pull-right">33</span>
    </li>
</ul>

<h1> show the content </h1>

<div class="show-content">
    <div id="item1">
        test1
    </div>
    <div id="item2">
        test2
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#checkbox1').on('change', function () {
            var checkbox1 = $('#checkbox1').is(':checked')

            if (checkbox1) {
                $(".show-content > #item1").hide();
            } else {
                $(".show-content > #item1").show();
            }

        });

        $('#checkbox2').on('change', function () {
            var checkbox2 = $('#checkbox2').is(':checked')

            if (checkbox2) {
                $(".show-content > #item2").hide();
            } else {
                $(".show-content > #item2").show();
            }

        });

    })
</script>
```